# Railstutorial missing sign in button on header

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, layout, header, railstutorial.org

it seems I cannot figure out how to display the "Sign In" button on the nav-bar menu from the Michael Hartl railstutorial Sample App.

I am currently on 9.3 and am getting failing tests.  I have tried going back through each different chapter to find out where I lost the sign-in button or how... I have rewritten much of the code hoping to fix the problem.  Anyways here is the code I have.

I am also noticing that my dropdown menu doesn't continue to display after logging out as a signed in user.

anyways..

my _header.html.erb

```
 <header class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse">
<div class="navbar-inner">
<div class="container">
  <%= link_to "sample app", root_path, id: "logo" %>
  <nav>
    <ul class="nav pull-right">
      <li><%= link_to "Home",    root_path %></li>
      <li><%= link_to "Help",    help_path %></li>

      <% if signed_in? %>
        <li><%= link_to "Users", 'users_path' %></li>
        <li id="fat-menu" class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
            Account <b class="caret"></b>
          </a>
          <ul class= "dropdown-menu">
            <li><%= link_to "Profile", current_user %></li>
            <li><%= link_to "Settings", edit_user_path(current_user) %></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li>
              <%= link_to "Sign out", signout_path, method: "delete" %>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    <% else %>
      <li><% link_to "Sign in", signin_path %></li>
    <% end %>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

and my application.html.erb

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title><%= full_title(yield(:title)) %></title>
   <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", media: "all" %>
   <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
   <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
   <%= render 'layouts/shim' %>    
 </head>
 <body>
   <%= render 'layouts/header' %>
   <div class="container">
     <% flash.each do |key, value| %>
       <div class="alert alert-<%= key %>"><%= value %></div>
     <% end %>
     <%= yield %>
     <%= render 'layouts/footer' %>
     <%= debug(params) if Rails.env.development? %>
    </div>
  </body>
 </html>
```

application.js

```
// This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.js, which will includeall the files
// listed below.
//
// Any JavaScript/Coffee file within this directory, lib/assets/javascripts, vendor/assets/javascripts,
// or vendor/assets/javascripts of plugins, if any, can be referenced here using a relative path.
//
// It's not advisable to add code directly here, but if you do, it'll appear at the bottom of the
// the compiled file.
//
// WARNING: THE FIRST BLANK LINE MARKS THE END OF WHAT'S TO BE PROCESSED, ANY BLANK LINE SHOULD
// GO AFTER THE REQUIRES BELOW.
//
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

routes.rb

```
SampleApp::Application.routes.draw do

  resources :users
  resources :sessions, only: [:new, :create, :destroy]
  root to: 'static_pages#home'              

  match '/signup',  to:'users#new'          
  match '/signin',  to: 'sessions#new'
  match '/signout', to: 'sessions#destroy', via: 'delete'
  match '/help',    to: 'static_pages#help'
  match '/about',   to: 'static_pages#about'
  match '/contact', to: 'static_pages#contact'  


end
```

authemtication_pages_spec.rb

```
 require 'spec_helper'

 describe "Authentication" do

  subject { page }

  describe "signin page" do
    before { visit signin_path }

    it { should have_selector('h1',    text: 'Sign in') }
    it { should have_selector('title', text: full_title('Sign in')) }
  end

  describe "signin" do
    before { visit signin_path }

    describe "with invalid information" do
        before{ click_button "Sign in" }

        it { should have_selector('title', text: full_title('Sign in')) }
        it { should have_selector('div.alert.alert-error', text: 'Invalid')}

        describe "after visiting another page" do
            before { click_link "Home" }
            it { should_not have_selector ('div.alert.alert-error') }
        end
    end



     describe "valid information" do
        let (:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
        before { sign_in user }


         it { should have_selector('title',         text: full_title(user.name)) }
        it { should have_link('Profile',          href: user_path(user)) }
      it { should have_link('Settings',     href: edit_user_path(user)) }
        it { should have_link('Sign out',         href: signout_path) }
        it { should_not have_link('Sign in',    href: signin_path) }

      describe "followed by signout" do
        before { click_link "Sign out" }
        it { should have_link('Sign in',    href: signin_path) }
      end
    end
    describe "authorization" do

       describe "for non-signed-in users" do
        let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }

        describe "in the Users controller" do
          before { visit edit_user_path(user) }
          it { should have_selector('title', text: full_title('Sign in')) }
        end

        describe "submitting to the update action" do
          before { patch user_path (user) }
          specify { expect(response_.to redirect_to(signin_path)) }
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

users_controller.rb

```
 require 'spec_helper'

 describe "User pages" do

   subject { page }

   describe "profile page" do
let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
before { visit user_path(user) }

it { should have_selector('h1', text: user.name) }
it { should have_selector('title', text: user.name) }
```

end

```
  describe "signup page" do
before { visit signup_path }

it { should have_selector('h1',    text: 'Sign up') }
it { should have_selector('title', text: full_title('Sign up')) }
```

end

```
  describe "signup" do

before { visit signup_path }

let(:submit) { "Create my account" }

describe "with valid information" do

  before do
    fill_in "Name",         with: "Example User"
    fill_in "Email",        with: "user@example.com"
    fill_in "Password",     with: "foobar"
    fill_in "Confirmation", with: "foobar"
  end

  it "should create a user" do
     expect { click_button submit }.to change(User, :count).by(1)
   end

  describe "after saving the user" do
    before { click_button submit }
    let(:user) { User.find_by_email('user@example.com') }

    it { should have_link('Sign out') }
    it { should have_selector('title', text: user.name) }
    it { should have_selector('div.alert.alert-success', text: 'Welcome') }
  end
end
  end

   describe "edit" do
let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
before do
  sign_in user
  visit edit_user_path(user)
end

describe "page" do
  it { should have_content("Update your profile") }
  it { should have_selector('title', text: full_title('Edit user'))}
  it { should have_link('change', href: 'http://gravatar.com/emails') }
end

describe "with invalid information" do
  before { click_button "Save changes" }

  it { should have_content('error') }
end

describe "with valid information" do
  let(:new_name)  { "New Name" }
  let(:new_email) { "new@example.com" }
  before do
    fill_in "Name",         with: new_name 
    fill_in "Email",        with: new_email
    fill_in "Password",     with: user.password
    fill_in "Confirmation", with: user.password
    click_button "Save changes"
  end

  it { should have_selector('title', text: new_name) }
  it { should have_selector('div.alert.alert-success') }
  it { should have_link('Sign out', href: signout_path) }
  specify { expect(user.reload.name).to   eq new_name}
  specify { expect(user.reload.email).to   eq new_email}
    end
  end
end
```

gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
# ruby '2.0.0'
# Commented out , on version of Ruby 1.9.3
gem 'rails', '3.2.13'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '2.1'
gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '3.0.1'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'
group :development, :test do
gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.5'
gem 'rspec-rails', '2.11.0'
end

# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.5'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.2'
  gem 'uglifier', '1.2.3'
 end

  # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
  # gem 'therubyracer', :platforms => :ruby

gem 'turbolinks', '1.3.0'
gem 'jquery-rails', '2.0.2'

group :test do
gem 'capybara', '1.1.2'
gem 'factory_girl_rails', '4.2.1'
end

group :production do
gem 'pg', '0.12.2'
end

# To use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'

# To use Jbuilder templates for JSON
# gem 'jbuilder'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Deploy with Capistrano
# gem 'capistrano'

# To use debugger
# gem 'debugger'
```

I might have missed some necessary files.  Please let me know how else I may assist anyone that may be able to help.

Thank you!!

Answer (score 3):

You're going to hate this, but it's really simple.

```
<%= link_to "Sign in", signin_path %>
```

will place whatever is returned from the code into your HTML, while

```
<% link_to "Sign in", signin_path %> # (note the lack of an equals sign)
```

will simply execute the code and not display it.

So you need to be using `<%= %>` instead of `<% %>`.

Just add an equals sign!

**UPDATE**

As far as your dropdown not showing once you're signed out, you're specifically telling it not to show by putting it inside the part of the loop that shows when signed in:

```
<% if signed_in? %>
  # Show this code when signed in (this is where your dropdown is)
<% else %>
  # Show this code when not signed in (this is where your login button is)
<% end %>
```

Comment: I greatly appreciate you solving this issue.  You also helped me understand the code.. bravo!!

Comment: not enough rep to vote up but if someone else would that would be nice.  Thank you!!

Comment: The one think I am finding is that with the missing dropdown it is:
upon signin.
after clicking account to see the dropdown bar works.  upon clicking any # link, the account dropdown bar fails to work any longer... upon reloading page or clicking profile, it functions again until it no longer appears upon click.

thanks again for resolving the <%= %>